# Linq with Aggregate inside Join

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do an aggregate inside a join. I have a workload which comprises many samples and I want to construct a "mini" Workload object which has some properties from Workload and others which are aggregated (e.g. max) from the child entity sample. I am using a LINQ join to combine the entities which works well, but I cannot do the aggregate.

```
var workloads = Ctx.Workloads
 .Join(Ctx.Samples, 
       s => s.WorkloadId, 
       w => w.WorkloadId, 
      (w, s) => new { s, w })
         .Select(x => new MiniWorkload()
                {
                    WorkloadId = x.w.WorkloadId,
                    WorkloadName = x.w.WorkloadName,
                    MaxOfSampleDate = Max(x.s.SampleDate)
                });
```

The third line `MaxOfSampleDate = Max(x.s.SampleDate)` is made up and does not compile, but hopefully expresses what I want - the max SampleDate of the child entities.

How do I do this?

Comment: Make SampleDate a list object where is is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `GroupJoin`:

```
var workloads = Ctx.Workloads
 .GroupJoin(Ctx.Samples, 
            s => s.WorkloadId, 
            w => w.WorkloadId, 
            (w, ss) => new { ss, w })
            .Select(x => new MiniWorkload()
                    {
                        WorkloadId = x.w.WorkloadId,
                        WorkloadName = x.w.WorkloadName,
                        MaxOfSampleDate = x.ss.Max(s => s.SampleDate)
                    });
```

This method joins two sequences based on key selector functions and groups **all resulting matches** for each element.